# Feel or feel himself?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

What is the correct variant:

1. To help the consumer feel like the person he always wanted to become.
2. To help the consumer feel himself like the person he always wanted to become.

Comment: 1. The second one implies he is touching himself

Comment: Thank you very much))

Comment: @Mila - not always, although I agree that many people will mainly think that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Feel** and **feel like** can be used in several different ways, referring to direct touch, and to indirect sensations or ideas. It's complicated because "feel like" is an idiomatic phrasal verb, but "like" also occurs in many other structures.

1. In sentences like "He feels happy" or "He feels like a cat". It is describing a sensation or impression. The structure is subject + "feel(s)" + adjectival phrase.
2. "Feel" can take a direct object to describe what something feels like when you touch it, e.g. "This feels like silk". Here "like silk" is again an adjectival phrase (as in "Rayon is like silk.")
3. You can also use "feels" and "feels like" as verbs to express a thought, impression, or suspicion, e.g. "He feels John is tricking him" or "He feels like John is tricking him". These both have essentially the same meaning with or without "like" (the latter maybe less formal). Here the verb is followed by a finite clause ("John is tricking him").
4. "Feel" can also be followed by a non-finite clause ("He feels John to be dishonest.") This is expressing an idea or belief about a person or thing. However, this cannot be done with "feel like".
5. You also get a variation of 4 in a sentence like "He feels himself a lucky man." This could be rephrased as "He feels himself to be a lucky man." Basically "to be" is deleted.
6. "Feels like" can be used to express a temporary desire, e.g. "He feels like an ice cream."

There are many other ways you can use "feel", with or without "like".

To put something close to your phrase in a sentence: "This product aims to help the consumer feel like the person he always wanted to become." This is case 1: it is describing the sensation the consumer has.

"To help the consumer feel himself like the person he always wanted to become" is not quite right. You can "feel yourself something" (case 5), meaning feel like you are something, or you can "feel yourself" meaning you literally touch yourself. If you insert "to be" you get "To help the consumer feel himself to be like the person he always wanted to become", which is less ambiguous but a bit ungainly. Hence your first option is better: "To help the consumer feel like the person he always wanted to become."

See: [Feel](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/feel), Merriam-Webster.

Comment: Thank you very much)))

Comment: After a person was in a car wreck they might feel themselves all over, to make sure they still had all their arms and legs.